# Accessibility of games, how is important for you?

Tags: accessibility

I'm blind and I would know if there is someone that consider important the accessibility, from a blind in particular, when develop a new game.
I don't speak about an audio game, I'm speaking about a video game that implements a TTS or a GUI compatible with screen readers!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, right now, "games that blind people can play" are pretty much just audio games. The problem is that a lot of modern games rely heavily on visuals, for feedback and as an interface. In addition, many games require fast reflexes, and a TTS or screen reader would slow the player down quite a lot.  Additionally, most games use a different output system than the built in operating system one, and screen readers are probably not built to handle that.

For now, designing a game that works well for a blind person and a sighted person would be tricky. There's probably a few games that are like this, but they most likely have very good sound design, as well as audio cues for different menu items.  I can't think of too many that fit this requirement.

Finally, there's likely some companies out there who design games specifically for accessibility, but the quality of those games might vary by a large amount, and the games are almost certainly more expensive than a typical game.

Comment: Don't forget, there's a significant following of blind players for interactive fiction that work with the accessibility tools that Filippo mentioned. Check out the documentary Get Lamp to see examples (http://www.getlamp.com/). Granted, I.F. and text adventures are still a pretty niche genre, but it's something to think about.

Comment: @ thedaian : well, I begun blind five years ago and I know the world of video games...

Comment: @ thedaian : I want to say that, for me, the real problem is that the companies don't see the advantage to create a GUI accessible... An example? Football Manager? Can you tell me which is the problem to create a "audio GUI"?

Comment: @ bearcdp : thanks for your comments! Now I will see the site that you linked!

Comment: @Filippo1980 sadly, like many other things in life, the decision is based in money: if money_earnt/money_spent > 1, it's a possible feature (I think this is called ROI, Return on Investment, in economics.)